# Display array from factory in angularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, controller, factory

I'm trying to display 1 of the 2 arrays, this is my factory:

```
App.factory('NieuwsService', ['BERKVENS_NIEUWS', 'SVEDEX_NIEUWS', function (BERKVENS_NIEUWS, SVEDEX_NIEUWS) {
    var nieuwsService = {};

    var _nieuws = [];

    var _loadNieuws = function (url) {
        switch (url) {
        case 'berkvens':
            _nieuws = BERKVENS_NIEUWS;
            break;
        case 'svedex':
            _nieuws = SVEDEX_NIEUWS;
            break;
        }
    }

    nieuwsService.loadNieuws = _loadNieuws;
    nieuwsService.nieuws = _nieuws;

    return nieuwsService;

}]);
```

This is the code of my controller:

```
App.controller('instellingenCtrl', function ($scope, NieuwsService) {
    var url = 'berkvens';

    angular.copy(NieuwsService.loadNieuws(url));

    $scope.message= NieuwsService.nieuws[1].title;
});
```

But it wouldn't work.

**So how do I choose that I want the array 'berkvens' and how do I show it then ?**

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1et63rxq/)**

Comment: Where and how does 'BERKVENS_NIEUWS' and 'SVEDEX_NIEUWS' are defined? A fiddle with what you tried so far could help.

Comment: it would be better if you added `BERKVENS_NIEUWS` value in your questions.

Comment: What do you mean ? @gauravbhavsar

Comment: I edited the post, there is a fiddle now. @Quad

Comment: @Goldenowner I added working plunker in my answer, and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need `nieuwsService.nieuws = _nieuws;` in your service.
You just need to `return _nieuws` after `case :` condition.

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LFAdnnsLaljPbdJZX7AB?p=preview)

**Factory**

```
App.factory('NieuwsService', ['BERKVENS_NIEUWS', 'SVEDEX_NIEUWS', function (BERKVENS_NIEUWS, SVEDEX_NIEUWS) {
    var nieuwsService = {};

    var _nieuws = [];

    var _loadNieuws = function (url) {
        switch (url) {
        case 'berkvens':
            _nieuws = BERKVENS_NIEUWS;
            return _nieuws; // return _nieuws if case 'berkvens'
        case 'svedex':
            _nieuws = SVEDEX_NIEUWS;
            return _nieuws; // return _nieuws if case 'svedex'
        }
    }

    nieuwsService.loadNieuws = _loadNieuws;

    return nieuwsService;

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
App.controller('instellingenCtrl', function ($scope, NieuwsService) {
    var url = 'berkvens';

    // copy loadNieuws  
    var copyLoadNieuws = angular.copy(NieuwsService.loadNieuws(url));

    $scope.message= copyLoadNieuws[1].title;
});
```

Comment: can you use `console.log(copyLoadNieuws)` to check what you getting ? error is saying `copyLoadNieuws` is `undefined` in your controller.

Comment: check Plunker, I added in answer